# Add callbacks to controller actions

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I would like to add a rescue clause to all my controller actions that is called if no other piece of code manages to rescue the exception.

I would like to send this exception to myself over mail.

Is it possible to wrap all controller actions in my own function, without duplication?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this in `router.ex`

```
def call(conn, opts) do
    try do
      super(conn, opts)
    rescue
        _ in UndefinedFunctionError -> mail_error("fun not found")
        e in _ -> mail_error("generic error")
    end
  end
```